# How to compute fraction sums?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For example, $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$
Is there an easier way to evaluate fraction sums (without using partial sums)?

Comment: Problems like this are usually rather hard. However, the problems you will be assigned will usually be ones that succumb to tricks, such as being arranged into a telescoping sum. Using those tricks, or ideas related to those tricks, are pretty much your only options for simplifying the sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general approach which works quite well is [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition):
$$
\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{(2k+1)}\right)
$$
After this, you can use the technique of [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

In your example, this yields:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)}-\frac{1}{(2k+1)}\right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+…+\frac{1}{2n-3}-\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right) = \frac{n}{2n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could telescoping be used when the numerator is different from $1$?

Comment: Yes, for example I have seen a question that asked for the sum of $\frac{n}{n^4 + 4}$, which also uses partial fraction decomposition. However it's often seen with 1 in the numerator but there's no reason why not.

Answer (score 4):

**An "easier way" as requested.**

If you know (or can guess) the answer, then you can show that 
$$\frac 1{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac k{2k+1}-\frac {k-1}{2k-1}$$
which allows you complete the summation by telescoping immediately without the need for decomposing into partial fractions in the traditional way.